# Python Exception for escaped quotes within exception for quotes

Tags: python, regex, csv

I want adapt a csv from comma-separated to tab-separated. There are also commas between quotes, so I need an exception for that. So, some googling and stackoverflow got me this:

```
import re
f1 = open('query_result.csv', 'r')
f2 = open('query_result_tab_separated.csv', 'w')
for line in f1:
    line = re.sub(',(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])', '\t', line)
f2.write(line)
f1.close()
```

However, between the quotes I also find escaped quotes \". An example of a line:

```
"01-003412467812","Drontmann B.V.",1,6420,"Expert in \"Social, Life and Tech Sciences\""
```

My current code changes the comma after Social into a tab as well, but I don't want this. How can I make an exception for quotes and within that exception and exception for escaped quotes?

Comment: Use the stdlib's `csv` module (for both reading and writing), it knows how to take care of this problem.

Comment: It's tough. Things between quotes are no longer "Regular expressions" because this is an irregular pattern. Use a csv parser instead like `csv` or `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: May be like this: [`,(?="|\d+(?:,|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/rv4Jf2/2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with regexp.

Python has a `csv` module which is intended to do this:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
    for row in data:
        print ' | '.join(row)
```

Comment: Damn, I read the doc and I tried but I didn't use two slashes (and after that I thought of regex). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module can handle this. You can set the escape character and specify how quotes within a field are escaped using [`escapechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar) and [`doublequote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote):

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as infile, open('file_tabs.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    r = csv.reader(infile, doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
    w = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', doublequote=False, escapechar='\\')
    w.writerows(r)
```

This will create a new tab delimited file that preserves the commas and escaped quotes within a field from the original file. Alternatively, the default settings will use `""` (double quote) to escape the quotes:

```
w = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
```

which would write data like this:

```
01-003412467812 Drontmann B.V.  1   6420    "Expert in ""Social, Life and Tech Sciences"""
```